# Does force close of a Java application cause Database connection leakage

Tags: java, database, netbeans

While running a Java application from NetBeans, and the application connects to a remote database, if we try to kill the application from NetBeans using the Stop button, will it cause a database connection leakage?

If so.. where should we set the properties to close all Database connections before killing the running instance of the application.

Comment: If your code leaks connection(s). Do you use a Connection Pool? Do you correctly close every Connection every time (in a `finally` block)?

Comment: Killing the application would make the connection dead on your DB side.  DB should timeout the connections after sometime. But if you application is starting and terminating quickly too many times without closing connections properly, you might end using up all the connections you DB can provide.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes the Connection is closed in the finally block

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes the connection is closed in the finally block.

Comment: @Nishan Is Netbeans then handling it?

Comment: I just tried a sysout in the `finally` block, it's never reached when I kill the program through the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sides where a connection can be leaked.

**Within the Java software:**

You really can ignore this because the application will be killed soon.

**Within the database:**

This will cause problems, **BUT** every single network server application will check if a connection breaks away and free resources.

So I don't think you will get problems, because the database will mark the connections as invalid and free all resources.